# Delete file in variable directory with VBScript

Tags: variables, batch-file, vbscript

I need use vbscript to delete some browser files.
I have simple batch code like

```
del /q /s /f "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Current Session"
rd /s /q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Current Session"
```

In vbs

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile("C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Current Session")
```

Problem is that vbs doesn't recognize variable %USERNAME% and I am getting error "no file in this directory". 
Could someone tell me how to write variable directory/path in this language?

Comment: Removing C++ tag, since that is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

From Help.

Returns an environment variable's expanded value.

```
object.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strString)
```

**imageArguments**
**object**
WshShell object.

**strString**
String value indicating the name of the environment variable you want to expand.

**Remarks**
The ExpandEnvironmentStrings method expands environment variables defined in the PROCESS environment space only. Environment variable names, which must be enclosed between "%" characters, are not case-sensitive.

**imageExample**
The following code expands the Windows Directory environment variable and displays it:

**Visual Basic Script**

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo "WinDir is " & WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WinDir%")
```

If you want to do it in vbs you use recursion.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ProcessFolder "c:\users\david candy\documents"

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set Fls = fldr.files
    For Each thing in Fls
        wscript.echo thing.path
    Next
    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing in fldrs
'        wscript.echo thing.name
        ProcessFolder thing.path
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UserProfile = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
Wscript.echo UserProfile
Wscript.echo UserProfile &"\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Current Session"
AppData = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%")
Wscript.echo AppData
Wscript.echo AppData &"\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Current Session"
If objFSO.FolderExists(AppData &"\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Current Session") Then
    objFSO.DeleteFolder AppData &"\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Current Session"
End If
```

Comment: Could you give me mail/jabber/icq to you?